# What causes skulls to be dropped by enemies?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

I've noticed that enemies will occasionally drop skulls. I've mostly seen it after doing a particularly large combo.

If combos are causing the drops, level combo do you need to cause a skull to drop?

If they aren't causing the drops, what causes skulls to be dropped by enemies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any official source, but I did some testing, and it doesn't seem to be affected by weapon/trap choice, combo-length, or kill-streak.

In short, **it's probably completely random**, just like the coin-drops from the scavenger trinket.

Comment: I sort of suspected it was completely random. I figure I noticed it after long combos because a lot of orcs just died in most cases.